# How to determine if app is installed via education store?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, app-store, analytics

The iOS App Store offers schools 50% discounts on bulk purchases which is great. Is there a way to determine, at the app's runtime, if the app was installed via an educational purchase?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At runtime? No. There is no way to get any information about the purchase of your app.

In sales reports, thats another question.

I would assume attempting to modify functionality of the app based on educational purchase is against apple's rules. Your contract states:

> In addition, you may, at your election via iTunes Connect, instruct Apple to market the Licensed Applications at a discount of 50% of Your established price tier for authorized institutional customers.

Which sounds to me like you can optionally agree to ship the same app but at a reduced price.

Comment: Unfortunately this is probably the right answer. Apple really is quite annoying that they won't tell you *anything* about your users.